# Rendering from command line script that allows specifying which camera to use / render with

Tags: rendering, scripting, camera, command-line

I have a command line script below that can render an image of frame 193 of a blend file using the default camera below, but how can I specify another camera view (specify which camera to use / render with) to use for rendering?

If a camera was called **camera_1_setup** I would render with the camera / camera view called **camera_1_setup** and it would render using that camera view.

```
#Render image in Cycles
blender -b /home/user1/Documents/blender/blenderfile1.blend -E CYCLES -o /tmp/frame_cycles_##### -f 193;
```

Comment: I have the same need, I've been looking for a while but haven't found a solution. In the end I am writing an addon to automate the rendering on multiple cameras.

Comment: By camera view do you mean orthographic/perspective, the camera views, that you get into with the numpad keys, just a different camera or something else?

Comment: @WhatAMesh If a camera was called `camera_1_setup` I would render with the camera / camera view called `camera_1_setup` and it would render using that camera view.

Comment: I think the only way is using a python expression changing the scene camera.

Comment: @brockmann I guess executing a python script from the terminal prompt would work to, any examples?

Comment: Have a look into the manual or add `-h` when calling the executable: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html Either use `-P` to specify a file or an expression `--python-expr 'import bpy; C.scene.camera...' `